# Signing wildcard cert for a subdomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I want to use my issued wildcard certificate to generate an SSL cert for a  subdomain E.g. *.bar.com -> foo.bar.com

Reason being I want to attempt to prevent some XSS weaknesses caused by multiple application running on the same domain.

I don't know if this is even possible, hopefully someone could tell me if it is or isn't.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.
To use an existing certificate to sign another certificates it must have the appropriate purpose and extension set, so that it can work as a CA (certificate authority). End user certificates don't have this extension. You would probably be able to use your certificate to sign a new one, but this new certificate could then not be validated because the issuer certificate is no CA.